# Facebook OpenGraph DateTime attribute with only date being parsed as DateTime

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm having issues with Facebook `OpenGraph` and a `DateTime` attribute that I'm setting on my page.

The tag looks like this:

```html
<meta content="2013-06-10" property="app:departing_on" />
```

The tag is properly set as `DateTime` on the `OpenGraph` type. I'm using it to create a new Story. When I simulate a post, it changes the timezone to match mine (UTC-3), so I get June 09th, 2013 at 9:00PM. It is a date only event and so I don't actually have a time to display, just a date.

Can I force Facebook to parse it as a date?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I force Facebook to parse it as a date?

That’s what its seems to be doing right now, but it does not seem to be what you want.

I think what [Facebook docs call the *Precise-time* format](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) might be what you should rather use:

> *Precise-time (e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700'): events that start at a particular point in time, in a specific offset from UTC. This is the way new Facebook events keep track of time, and allows users to view events in different timezones.*

Which formats you can use to specify the OG DateTime type you can see here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#simple

Comment: Thanks for the documentation page, I couldn't find this specific one. It bugs me even more, given their example shows a date-only parameter that is supposed to be parsed as a date. I don't want my event to start at midnight, I want it to be a full-day event.

Answer (score 1):

### Can I force Facebook to parse it as a date?

No. Facebook does not support at `Date` property, only a `DateTime` property.  While it is optional for you to specify the time portion of a `DateTime`, the property nevertheless includes a time component and is recorded as such. Facebook wants things to happen at a specific moment in time, not a range like a date.

Comment: @CBroe's documentation link shows Facebook's own example with a Date. I'm supposed to use DateTime for dates also, according to the docs.

Comment: @Pedro, yes, the documents show you can set a DateTime from a date string, just like you are doing, and it works just like you observe: it sets the DateTime to midnight on that date.  Times specified on Events are not DateTimes, they are Strings in ISO-8601 date format. You can do that (save the date as String rather than a DateTime) if you want.

Comment: But it is not even using midnight at that date, but considering timezone. It is a weird behavior.

Comment: Facebook is setting the DateTime to midnight UTC and displaying it in the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching Facebook’s documentation, it appears as though the time format is optional, as per this documentation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties (search for `DateTime`).